# JS cookie: cannot set path

Tags: javascript, cookies

Both statements fail to set cookies path to the desired value:

```
 $.cookie('name', 'value', { path: "abc/de" });
 document.cookie = "username=John Smith; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=abc/de";
```

The actual path is always set to the controller:

[image]

Background:
I have two kendo grids whose selected emelents I want to store in a cookie.
Somehow I need to distinguish between both grids that only differ in path.

Shouldn't be this exactly what path is ment for?

Comment: Could it be that your `expires` date is set to the past? This could prevent the cookie from being set.

Comment: like you can see in the example the cookies are beeing set

Comment: Path is an absolute path to the domain the cookie is on....

Comment: Why don't you use different names?

Comment: Well I could but I want to know why the path option is not working. You say it should be a full qualified (absolute) Url containing the domain? Can you give an example? Where is the documentation?

Comment: @el_buck0 — They said "absolute path" not "absolute URL". Absolute paths start with a `/`.

Comment: Okay but I understand that path should be rather the relative path to the domain?

Comment: @el_buck0 — "the relative path to the domain" is not a phrase that makes sense.

Comment: document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";domain=localhost;path=/MyAdmin/Offering/Courses";  is working fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.4):

> If the attribute-name case-insensitively matches the string "Path",
> the user agent MUST process the cookie-av as follows.
>
> If the attribute-value is empty or if the first character of the
> attribute-value is not %x2F ("/"):
>
> ```
>   Let cookie-path be the default-path.
> ```
>
> Otherwise:
>
> ```
>   Let cookie-path be the attribute-value.
> ```
>
> Append an attribute to the cookie-attribute-list with an attribute-
> name of Path and an attribute-value of cookie-path.

Since the first character of your path is `a` and not `/`, the value is invalid and is ignored.

You must provide an absolute path (such as `/foo/bar/abc/de`).